# Print statement only once in a while loop (Python, Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium

```
driver.get("Link of product site.")
while "Not available right now." in driver.page_source:
print("Not available right now, reloading site until it is available..")
driver.refresh()
sleep(45)

else:
print("It is available! Gonna order it now..")
```

The problem here is that it gives me lots of print statements every 45 seconds. How is it possible that it gives the statement "Not available right now, reloading site until it is available.." only once until the else statement is true?

(Written in Python, Selenium)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Code won't work; it's missing some pieces; there is no context. Please [read how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Alright, changed it. Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the order of your code, and you don't need an `if..else` statement.  Let it default to "Checking availability...", and then start your loop which will refresh the page every 45 seconds until that text you specified is gone from `driver.page_source`

```
driver.get("Link of product site.")
print("Checking availability...")
while "Not available right now." in driver.page_source:
    sleep(45)
    driver.refresh()
    

print("It is available! Gonna order it now..")
```

If it is available immediately it will just print these both out right after each other..

```
Checking availability...
It is available! Gonna order it now..
```

Otherwise there will be a time delay between them.

If you want to add a timestamp so you know how long it took to become available use this:

```
import datetime

current_time = datetime.datetime.now()

driver.get("Link of product site.")
print("Checking availability...")
print(current_time)
while "Not available right now." in driver.page_source:
    sleep(45)
    driver.refresh()
    

print("It is available! Gonna order it now..")
print(current_time)
```

Comment: It's nicer to have sleep before the refresh, otherwise the page will be visually updated but the console output will be delayed.

Comment: @Niloct.  Good point.  Updated code to reflect

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!